# Magento special price is showing zero by default

Tags: price

I'm working on a site in magento where all product's special prize is showing zero by default, though I didn't set any special price for products.

for example,it showing->

Regular Price: $755.00

Special Price: $0.00

how to hide those special prices and make visible only for those products where special price is applicable? otherwise the default price should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

To hide Special Price make sure in that if special price is zero then don't write special price is 0.00 .

if you write special price is 0.00 he is display fronted special price is 0.00.

in short keep it empty if there is no special price.[image]

Comment: I checked my admin panel, and found out I didn't put special price value=0 even also I didn't set any date.Now the most interesting thing is if I put some value in special price field and select a valid date, the result is showing same.

Comment: I think you change your price.phtml file. please check your price.phtml file

Comment: because I test in my local machine it's working fine..

Comment: i didn't change my price.phtml file...but recently i installed 'related product manager' for related products...in my localhost also there is no problem....but on server its creating problem.

Comment: I already uninstalled this plugin but same problem is there.I already downloaded the from server and run it from localhost...now in localhost same problem arises.

Comment: then please contact with the extension support team they will help you..